# ScrollView animation stopping independent animation

Tags: swift, animation

I have a scrollView that I use to implement a side menu. in the main view I have a simple progress animation. Both the side menu view and main view are contained in the scrollview.

Unfortunately, when I scroll to show the side menu, the animation in the main stutters.

How do I prevent scrolling from interrupting my animation?

I have tried to put the call to the function that handles showing the side menu in a CATransaction block, but that didn't solve the problem.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately.  I shipped the app like that.

Comment: I found an answer to this shortly after asking. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32835858/animation-stops-when-scrolling-in-ui-scrollview. Worked for me!